# Zooming is missing after rotating the image

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation

I used pinch gesture for zooming. It's working fine. Using slider I am rotating that image. Rotation is also working perfect.
The problem after zooming, if I rotate the image, the zoom effect is missing. Here is the code I used for rotation

```
subView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(slider.value * 2*M_PI / slider.maximumValue);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1):

What is zooming? It is a transform. That’s all it is.

So your code comes along and rips out that transform and replaces it with a different transform.

```
// subView has zoom transform    
subView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(slider.value * 2*M_PI / slider.maximumValue);
// zoom transform overwritten
```

So you have wiped out the zoom.

Comment: I understand that. How to over come this scenario.

Comment: If you understand it I don’t see what the question is.